# Same mac addresses for all the IPs

Tags: mac-address, arp

So I'm on a public wifi network and I'm trying to do intrusive testing. The issue is that while doing arp scan all the IPs are returning the same mac addresse.

Comment: What do you mean "all the IPs are returning the same mac address" - by ARP?

Comment: And why do you think this is an issue?

Comment: @Zac67 this was the result when I scanned for the number of devices connected to the network (https://ibb.co/nJ4LFe) As you may see I'm able to see the IP of the devices but however mac addresses seem to be odd

Comment: @Teun Because I want to see if duplicating any two mac addresses could be detected.

Comment: You cannot use ARP across a router, so there really isn't any way to scan ARP on the public Internet. Layer-2 addresses are only valid or seen on the local LAN where the host with the address is connected. Routers strip off the layer-2 header, losing the layer-2 addressing, to get to the layer-3 packet in order to route the packet, and the router will build a new, different layer-2 header for the next leg of the packet's path. In any case, questions about networks not under your direct control are off-topic here.

Comment: Sounds like proxy-arp... or a NAT device.